# Displaying Portrait and Landscape Photos Correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My current table view looks like this:

[image]

Here is how my constraints are laid out in Xcode for the image:

[image]

As you can see the pictures, depending on whether they are landscape or portrait go beyond their designated constraints. For the portrait pictures, they "intrude" into the address label where as the landscape pictures gets cut off at the left of the screen. I would like it so that when the picture is landscape, the picture will not be cut off on it's left side. And when portrait, not "intrude" into the address label. Is there an easy auto layout constraint solution to this problem? If so, would you please share with me? If not, could you please share the programatic solution. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You need to keep the `UIImageView` height fix?

Comment: Nope that doesn't matter.

Comment: can you please send me you demo project or just `UITableView` Storyboard then I will configure the constraints for that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is a contentMode of the UIImageView!